# Loop value can not work inside knex in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I tried to get loop values inside knex function but I got final value of a loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    knex_in.raw(query).then(function (result) {
                    console.log(i)
    });

    }
```

Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter in your loop (`i`) is a global variable. On each iteration of your loop, you are creating a promise. By the time your promises have resolved, the loop is complete, therefore `i` is the final value.

The solution is to save the value of `i` in a scoped variable. This can be done in a few ways, here are two:

You can use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (depending on ES6 support)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 500);

}
```

Or you could store the value of `i` in a scoped variable by creating a function:

```js
function someFunction(value) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(value);
  }, 500);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  someFunction(i)
}
```